# Can pseudo elements be incorporated in MJML?

Tags: html-email, pseudo-element, mjml

I'm pretty new working with MJML, and I'm working on an email project where the visited links are a different color... Thus far, my understanding is that you cannot use pseudo-elements in MJML.  Does anyone know a way to do this?

For example, the link is normally blue, but once it's been clicked it becomes gray.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
<mjml>
  <mj-head>
    <mj-style>
        a.blah:hover {
          color: #00ff00!important;
        }
      </mj-style>
  </mj-head>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
        <mj-text font-size="20px" color="#F45E43" font-family="Verdana" >Hello <a href="#" class="blah">World</a></mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

You don't need the class necessarily (i.e. `a:hover`, and `<a href="#">`)

See also their documentation https://mjml.io/documentation/#mjml-style